# Rails: Having a button in a view call a method in a controller, route not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Hi I'm making a rails app that uses Zendesk API calls. I have a controller that uses two classes I defined

```
class TicketsController < ApplicationController

  require 'ticket_fields'
  require 'ticket_search'

  def getTickets
    @search_fields = SearchFields.new(client)
    @tickets = TicketSearch.new(client)
  end

  def search_tickets
    @ddcustomvalues = [params[:customer_company_id], params[:study_id], params[:type_id], params[:system_id]]
    @tickets.search_tickets(ddcustomvalues)
  end
end
```

One class SearchFields uses the api to load values I want to filter tickets by into arrays. My view then uses these values to populate drop down lists.

The other class TicketSearch looks like this.

```
class TicketSearch

  attr_reader :tickets, :text

  def initialize(client)
    @text = "query"
    @tickets = Array.new
    client.tickets.all do |resource|
      @tickets << resource
    end
  end


  def search_tickets(custom_search_fields)
    querystring = "type:ticket+tags:"
    custom_search_fields.each_with_index do |field, index|
      unless field == ""
        if index ==0
          querystring += "#{field}"
        else
          querystring += " #{field}"
        end
      end
    end

    @text = querystring

  end

end
```

What I want to happen in my view is when a button is pressed it changes the value of @text to the querystring generated by the drop down list options that were selected. I'm currently doing this for testing to see if my querystring is correct and the button works. What I eventually want it to do is send the querystring to the ZenDesk Server and returns the tickets I filtered for. the @tickets array would then be replaced with the filtered tickets the server returned. Currently my button code looks like this.

```
<%= button_to 'Search', :action => 'search_tickets' %>
```

with all the route code I've tried I either get an error upon starting the page. Or when I press the button nothing happens and the @text being displayed in my view remains "query". Can someone help explain what I need to do I don't quite understand how routes work.

==================================================================================

Hey so I made the changes you suggested and did some reading up on AJAX and js and I think I'm almost at the answer my view now looks like this

```
<div id="test" >
<%= render partial: 'text', locals: { text: @tickets.text} %>
<div id="test" >
```

and I created a partial _text file that looks like this

```
<p> Query: <%=text%> </p>
```

and a js file search_tickets.js.erb

```
$("#test").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'text', locals: { text: @tickets.text } ) %>");
```

any idea what may be going wrong everything loads up okay but the text remains the same in the partial i set up when i hit the button still

the console outputs this after the button is hit

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/tickets/search_tickets"):

so I guess it may actually be a routing error my route looks like this

```
resources :tickets do
    collection do
      put :search_tickets
    end
  end
```

and the form tag calling the path looks like this

```
  <%= form_tag search_tickets_tickets_path, remote: :true do %>
      <table>
          <tr>
            <td align = "left" valign="middle"> <font size = 4> Customer Company </font> </td>
            <td align = "left" valign="middle">
              <%= select_tag "customer_company_id", options_for_select(@search_fields.customer_companies), :prompt => "Select One" %>
            </td>
          </tr>
          ......
          <tr>
             <td> </td>
             <td align = "left" valign="middle">
              <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
             </td>
          </tr>
       </table>
    <% end %>
```

==================================================================================
(Update)

I think I fixed my last problem by changing my form tag to this

```
  <%= form_tag search_tickets_tickets_path(@tickets), method: :put, remote: :true do%>
```

however now I get this error from the terminal after I hit the button

NoMethodError (undefined method `search_ticket' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/tickets_controller.rb:15:in`search_tickets'

how would I pass @tickets as a parameter through my route because clearly its not accessible by search_tickets right now as its giving a nil class error.

Comment: It seems to me that you have a bacground of asp.net Webforms or JSF, where you click something and auto-update. It is different in rails, the separataion between the client and server is not hidden from you. One way to solve your problem is to add a form in your html and submit the page and in the search_tickets methods return the view of the getTickets. Here is a link to how render a specific view: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-an-action-s-view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Variables**

> when a button is pressed it changes the value of `@text` to the querystring generated

It looks to me like you're confused with the [`stateless`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol) nature of Rails - in that, just because a `view` has been rendered doesn't mean the values / variables are still available for use.

It was mentioned in the comments that it seems you're basing a lot on experience with other frameworks / programming patterns. The best way to describe your solution is that Rails has to "refresh" all your variables / values each time it processes a request; consequently meaning that if you send a button request - you'll have to perform the request as if it were the first one

---

**Ajax**

The bottom line is that you need to use an [`ajax` request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) to pull this off.

To do this, you'll be be best creating a `form` (not just a `button_to`), as this will give you the ability to send as many params as you want. You should use [`form_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :tickets do 
   collection do
      get :search_tickets
   end
end

#view
<%= form_tag tickets_search_tickets_path, remote: :true do %>
    ... #-> fields for your params
    <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

This will give you the ability to define the following in your controller:

```
#app/controllers/tickets_controller.rb
Class TicketsController < ApplicationController
   def search_tickets
    @ddcustomvalues = [params[:customer_company_id], params[:study_id], params[:type_id], params[:system_id]]
    @tickets.search_tickets(ddcustomvalues)

    respond_to do |format|
       format.js #-> loads /views/tickets/search_tickets.js.erb
       format.html
    end
  end
end

#app/views/tickets/tickets_search.js.erb
//JS here to manipulate your original page
```

---

**Requests**

The bottom line here is that if you want to "manipulate" your view without refreshing, unlike "native" application frameworks, where you can rely on a persistent state, with Rails, you basically have to construct the request from scratch (IE passing all the params required for the method to run)

[image]

Comment: This is all great information! Thanks do you know of any good sources where I could read more about this? My previous experience was with asp.net webforms as the other poster guessed, and I'm rather green to web development as a whole. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hey no problem! The best thing will be to check out http://railscasts.com or a new kid on the block http://gorails.com :)

Comment: Hey I ran into another problem I think its an issue with the way I set up the route if there's anyway you could take a look and offer some advice that'd be amazing. I edited my original question with the new problem.